# TexView: setText performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a SeekBar that when its value changes, four related TextViews are updated accordingly.

I am driving the event from the SeekBar to the TextViews via a Rx Subject.

What I observe is that if I omit the update of the TextViews, the SeekBar slides smoothly, whereas if I enable the TextViews update with the new values, then SeekBar sliding becomes sticky. It is like it is hard for the app to update the TextViews.

Is this expected behavoir? Is it that expensive to update textViews?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was consuming that much time: wrap_content.
For each text update, the size of the field changes, and the layout needed to be recalculated for the new size.

With fixed size, the behavior of the seekbar gets much smoother.